# Find the function of the vector field that makes $0$ the line integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Hey I want to solve this problem:

Let $F(x,y)=(cos(xy),g(x,y))$. Find a function $g(x,y)$ such that

$$ \int_{C} F=0$$

Where $C$ is the circle of radius $5$ and center $(1,-2)$.

So I tried to solve this by using the Green's Theorem, because by the "general" way to solve line integrals of vector fields results in a very complicated integral.

Applying Green's Theorem I need to find a $g(x,y)$ that makes zero the integral:

$$ \int_{-4}^{6} \int_{-a-2}^{a-2} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+ xsin(xy) \hspace{1mm} dy dx $$

Where $a= \sqrt{5^2-(x-1)^2}$

From here I said that one $g(x,y)$ can be

$$  \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=- xsin(xy)  $$

By integration:

$$ g(x,y)= -\frac{1}{y^2} \Big( -xycos(xy)+sin(xy)+C \Big)  $$

But, I'm not 100% sure that this solution can work... because that solution only help with $y \neq 0$...

How would you solve it? Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean $\int_C \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$?

Comment: @thedude   Yes! it is.